# Geographic Reasons for Phatic Expression "What's new?"

Tags: meaning

Quite a while back I had a language instructor tell me that the English phatic expression "What's new?" could be traced back in America to the fact that people lived very far apart from each other and so when they met a common point of reference would be to talk about news that each party had heard about that the other might not know about.

The instructor contrasted this with another idea that when compared to Japanese, that tend to talk more about the weather when they meet since that effected everyone equally and due to the relatively close living proximity to each other (when compared to America) that news traveled much quicker and thus was not usually a topic of conversation.

Is there any truth to these idea?
What kind of source could I use to start researching this? I have been finding a lot of things on what phatic expressions are and that different cultures have different topics, but nothing historical or possibly etymological.

Thank you!

Comment: British people are also famous for talking about the weather, probably because our weather is so unpredictable.  You don't say "What a lovely day!" in regions where it's always hot in summer.

Comment: ["What's new?"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what%27s_new) asks what is going on in the other person's life; it's a general conversation starter, not specifically asking for news in the sense of what you read in the papers. Compare "What's up?" So I don't see how distance would be relevant. I'm sure there are publications about these expressions but asking for resources is a bit off-topic here, more for Meta (and asking about Japanese is also off-topic here, maybe Linguistics SE).

Comment: It's bogus to bring America into the explanation. Hamlet asks Rosencrantz 'What news?"

Comment: I'm very not familiar with people asking/saying *"What's new?"* to me, but I'm inclined to think it isn't exactly "phatic" (i.e. - just an "ice-breaker", not a genuine inquiry). On the other hand, every other Youtube post I watch starts with *"What's up, guys?"* - which I'd say is as meaningless as it gets.

Comment: It confuses the matter somewhat to characterise this expression as phatic in the opening of the question, and then, in the same sentence, offer an explanation of its origins that treats it as a genuine request for needed, useful information. If that explanation is correct, then the expression was originally not phatic; its arguably being phatic now (which, as FumbleFingers points out, is debatable) is irrelevant to the correctness of the explanation. (If the explanation of the origin is correct, it would be an entirely separate question how the expression became phatic.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My dictionary gives "How are you?" as an example of a phatic question. "What's new?" is used almost identically, so I don't see why it wouldn't be phatic. Of course, it's possible to use both questions literally (if a friend is or was recently ill, you would ask for their current condition), but the phatic sense is more common.

Comment: While it's true that America is large, most people didn't travel very far from home frequently until well into the 20th century. So it's unlikely that distance played a part in the genesis of such an old expression.

Comment: This would have to do with the frequency that people see each other. *What’s new?* if it’s been a while, or e.g., *hot enough for you?* if it was yesterday.